# focal_hpc in R: input a matrix of weight for the focal processing

Tags: r, raster, spatial

I'm using the function `focal_hpc` from `spatial.tools` in R to compute for each cell of a raster the average value (`mean` function) around windows of a specific size (3 cells x 3 cells).

I used to perform this analysis using the similar function `focal`, which is however slower than `focal_hpc` when using large raster files.

The advantage of `focal` is that the user can specify a matrix of weights. However, `focal_hpc` does not seem to provide this option.

I have been trying to use a custom function, such as:

```
f_mean = function(x,weight_pix){
  x[is.na(x)]<-0
  weighted.mean(x,weight_pix)
}
```

However, I keep getting this error, which I do not really understand:

```
Error in weight_pix * x : non-conformable arrays
```

Do you have any suggestion?